# Why all update progresses on a page becomes active when only one update panel updates?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel, updateprogress

I have this problem in many of my projects. I added many update panels to various section of page, each containing an update progress with a "Loading..." text and image. Whenever I click a button in one update panel, all the update progress panels of the page becomes visible. Can anyone tell me why this happens? Why can't only the update progress of the update panel in which the operation is performed can be shown and all other update progress remain invisible?Is it a default behavior of asp.net's update panel and update progress? Or I am missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the 'AssociatedUpdatePanelId' property of the PanelProgress control with the ID of the UpdatePanel you want to target.